# When using an if else statement, program goes straight to else

Tags: c, if-statement

So after not coding in C for a while I wanted to make a simple test program where I would ask whether I liked a certain theme or not in Sublime Text

Here is the Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void )  {
    char A [ 2 ];
    printf ( "Do you like this theme? Answer Y or N: " );
    scanf ( "%d", A );

    if ( A == "Y" ) {
        printf ( "Good.\n" );
    } else {
        printf ( "Why not?\n" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I write an if else statement in which I tell the program if the input is "Y" then print Good. Makes sense right, well every time I run the program it goes straight to the else statement which asks Why not?

Here is the output:

```
C:\Users\           \Desktop>a
Do you like this theme? Answer Y or N: Y
Why not?

C:\Users\           \Desktop>
```

Not sure what the issue is been looking for a way to fix it for a while not but nothings seems to work. Any help would be great. And if you know a place to learn C, rather than reading a book, that would be really helpful as well.

Comment: Please include the minimal necessary amount of code in your question. Do not use links to other sites.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the links are to the screenshots of my code.

Comment: You can not compare in `C` string and char[] use `==`, use `strcmp`

Comment: What we mean is no screen shots of code. Paste the code as formatted text into the question.

Comment: Use `%1s` instead of `%d` and `A=="Y"` --> `*A=='Y'`

Comment: @DYZ @kaylum, my bad still new. @BLUEPIXY what does the `%1s` indicate and why would I use `*A` rather than just `A`?

Comment: `%1s`  accepts one character input. (It is necessary to limit two or more characters because it causes buffer overflow.) `A` is an array, it is not a character. `*A` is the same as `A[0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`A` is defined as characters array, so you should compare it to the input using `strncmp` function, and not `==`.

Better will be to define `A` as `char A`, and then to `scanf("%c", &A)`. Then, you could compare using `==`.

Comment: So because I'm dealing with `char` I would use `%c` rather than `%d` right, and I should use `&A` rather than just `A`?

Comment: Really curious - what's wrong with this (accepted) answer? brave down-voters - be brave and explain. Thanks